# Prove that Dyck language is subset of grammar

Tags: induction, formal-languages, formal-grammar

last two days I am trying to prove, that Dyck language $L$ over the alphabet $\{[, ]\}$ is a subset of the language $L(G)$ generated by the grammar with rules $\{S \rightarrow [S]S  |   \epsilon \}$.

Recommended steps by our lector are:

a) Prove that every nonepmty $w \in L$ can be written as $w = [u]v$, where $u,v$ $\in$ $L$

b) prove with induction where i is number of '[' in $w$ that L $\subseteq$ L(G), use a) in induction step

Thanks for any advice.

> Edit: I have solved the problem from *a*, but I do not know, if its
>   valid proof and how to solve *b*.
>
> a) Prove that every nonepmty $w \in L$ can be written as $w = [u]v$,
>   where $u,v$ $\in$ $L$:
>
> 1. $D = ( \{S'\}, \{[, ]\}, \{ S \rightarrow S'S'  | [S'] | \epsilon \}, S' )$ is a grammer defining Dyck language over alphabet $\{[,]\}$.
> 2. The only way to create $w \in L$ where $|w| > 0$ is to apply rule $\{S'\rightarrow[S'] \}$ at least once.
> 3. $w_1$: $S' \rightarrow [S'] \rightarrow^* w_1 $
> 4. $w_2$: $S \rightarrow S'S' \rightarrow^* S^i[S']S^j \rightarrow^* w_2 $ where $i, j \geq 0$
> 5. In 3rd case, $w = [u]v$, where $v = \epsilon$ and $u$ is generated from starting symbol, so $u, v \in L$. In 4th case, you have $w = [u]v$ where $u, v$ is generated from starting symbol $S'$ so $u, v \in
>     L$

Comment: Seems to me the language generated by [ and ] is larger than the language of proper pairings, It includes for example four [ 's and no ]'s. By Dyck language is there a restriction on what strings are in that language?

Comment: Dyck language (in our example) is a language, that is generated by grammar with rules S -> SS, S -> epsilon, S-> [S]

Comment: Your lector's advice seems pretty good to me. What is giving you trouble following it?

Comment: Your definition of the Dyck language is not correct; you only provide the alphabet it uses.

Comment: @rici I have problem with induction. I was able somehow prove a). Also I was able to prove induction where number of '[' is equal to i where i is from interval <0, |w|>, but was not able to prove it for i+1

Comment: @PeterLeupold Yes, I mentioned it that the definition is valid for this example.

Comment: That's a perfectly valid form of inductive proof, usually called complete or "strong" induction. You  prove P(i) if P(j) for all j < i. A web search will probably find you many explanations, this is just one: http://www.mathblog.dk/strong-induction/ .